# Error CS0029 Visual Studio Blazor, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I'm currently trying to get blazor working along with my Db and I'm getting this error.

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'App.Data.TipoFormacao' to 'App.Pages.TipoFormacao.TipoFormacao' App C:\VS\repos\App\Pages\TipoFormacao\TipoFormacaoController.cs
```

```
public async Task<TipoFormacao> Details(string id)
        {
            return await _dbContext.tipoFormacao.FindAsync(id);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_dbContext.tipoFormacao.FindAsync(id)` ius returning the type `App.Data.TipoFormacao` but `public async Task<TipoFormacao> Details(string id)` is referring to `'App.Pages.TipoFormacao.TipoFormacao'`. Try this to prove my point,`public async Task<App.Data.TipoFormacao.TipoFormacao> Details(string id)`. If that compiles, you can decide which type to use.

Comment: I have also had some problems, when I had a Type with the same name as the namespace it's in ...